# How to show plane is an affine plane？

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, projective-geometry

I know what an affine plane is .But I don't know how to prove that a plane is an affine plane. Can give me a proof example?

For example, prove that (P,L)is an affine plane:

P is the set of ordered pairs of numbers (x,y)(p.s (x,y)is not equal to (y,x))

L is p(x,y) that satisfying ax+by=c

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You will get a better response if you (a) include the definition of an affine plane in your post (b) explain where you had trouble verifying that the given $(P,L)$ satisfies the definition (c) use MathJax to format your question. Mathjax is mostly easy; just enclose all math formulas in `$`'s, and use `^` and `_` for super/subscripts. More mathjax info [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)